# How to show elements of a list using `<*ngIf>` and enum variable

Tags: html, angular, enums, angular-ng-if

I have a list mad with angular, and I want to show elements of this list, with an enum variable. For example if enum = 0 than it shows all elements, if enum = 1 it shows only elements with `list.status` = true and if enum = 2 it shows only elements wiht `list.status` = false.

```
<ul class="list" style="list-style-type:none">
    <div>
      <li *ngFor="let list of currentList">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="stat" (click)="status(list)" [(checked)]="list.status" />
          <span class="task">{{list.task}}</span>
          <button class="listBtn" (click)="edit(list)">EDIT</button>
          <button class="listBtn" (click)="remove(list)">REMOVE</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a method which returns a boolean after doing the check, something like

```
public checkEnum( list: any ): boolean {
  if ( enum == 0 ) {
   return true;
  }
  if ( enum == 1 && list.status == true ) {
   return true;
  }
  if ( enum == 2 && list.status == false ) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and then in the template:

```
    <div *ngIf="checkEnum(list)">
      <input type="checkbox" class="stat" (click)="status(list)" [(checked)]="list.status" />
      <span class="task">{{list.task}}</span>
      <button class="listBtn" (click)="edit(list)">EDIT</button>
      <button class="listBtn" (click)="remove(list)">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
```

See if it helps.

Comment: thanks, BTW how should I declare the enum? like this :

`enum ListEnum {
    all = 'all',
    completed = 'completed',
    uncompleted = 'uncompleted',
}`

Comment: You could do this like angular self does it (i.e. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/enums.ts#L13 ) or you could do it as a string, like `public ListEnum: 'all' | 'completed' | 'uncompleted' | null;` and set it respectively.